# How do I list the %TEMP% and %USERNAME% directory in C#?

Tags: c#, list, variables, path, directory

I am trying to list the files inside the directory %TEMP% and %USERNAME% in a text box so people can see what files exist there. When I type C:\users\%username%... It fails to work. 
Here is my code:

```
string strDirLocal = @"C:\users\USERPROFILE\desktop";
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(strDirLocal))
{
   foreach (string sPath in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(strDirLocal, "*.*"))
   {
       textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + sPath.Replace(strDirLocal + @"\", "") + "\r\n";
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is expand the `%TEMP%` and `%USERPROFILE%` environment variables in your program and use the result instead of the variable

```
string userProfile = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE");
string strDirLocal = Path.Combine(userProfile, "desktop");
```

Answer (score 2):

[Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
```

`Environment.GetFolderPath` also gives access to a lot of other special folder paths, such as CD Burning, and Logical Desktop & Virtual Desktop locations.